# brz: ERROR: unknown command "dh-make"

Tags: packaging, bazaar, dh-make

I'm trying to build a deb according to the https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html
Everything was working 6 months ago. Now when I execute: `bzr dh-make hello 2.10 hello-2.10.tar.gz` I'm getting:

```
brz: ERROR: unknown command "dh-make"
```

I tried to apt install -reinstall: bzr, bzr-builddeb, dh-make
That doesn't help. My packages are:

bzr            2.7.0+bzr6622+brz
bzr-builddeb   2.8.12+brz
devscripts     2.21.1ubuntu1
dh-make        2.202003

```
$ python -V
Python 3.9.5
```

System: Kubuntu 21.04

What can be wrong and how to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, It seems `dh-make` command support was removed from bzr plugins (package `brz-debian`) since ver 2.8.51:

```
breezy-debian (2.8.51) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Drop the dh-make subcommand.
```

https://github.com/breezy-team/breezy-debian/blob/master/debian/changelog#L74

The solution is to downgrade brz-debian (2.8.51) to brz-debian (2.8.42) from Ubuntu 20.04:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/breezy-debian/brz-debian_2.8.42_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i brz-debian_2.8.42_all.deb
```

Comment: The Ubuntu documentation is outdated and should be changed; even with older versions of brz-debian, it was almost certainly broken.

Comment: Is there a solution nowaday? I'm get exactly the same problem right now. In addition, the version 2.8.42 there isn't on focal store, but only 2.8.32 or 2.8.51

Comment: @dharman, I guess you still can download and install the package manually then you can freeze it from the auto upgrade with `apt-mark hold brz-debian`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Ok, I can download but... from where? At the  URL
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/breezy-debian/ there are only versions 2.8.32, 2.8.51 and up

Comment: According to the changelog the `dh-make` command drop happened in 2.8.51. So you may try something older. Have you tried 2.8.32?